nested route path is not working inside lazy loaded named router outlet
In my angular app-routing.module I am loading a module name layout.module ,in layout module I am loading a module ftl.module, in ftl module ftl-order component is visibale if path is blank,but it is not working if I set path:'new-order' or any string .I want to add more route but not able to add.I want to show ftl-order component if url is localhoset/shipper/ftl/new-order.
app-routing code
{
    path: 'shipper', canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/features/layout/layout.module').then(m => m.LayoutModule),
  },

layout module code
{
    path: 'dashboard', component: AppLayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: '', outlet: 'layout', component: HomeComponent },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'ftl', component: AppLayoutComponent, children: [
      {
        path: '', outlet: 'layout', loadChildren: () => import('../ftl/ftl.module').then(m => m.FTLModule)
      },
    ]
  },

ftl module code
{
    path: '',
    component: FtlOrderComponent,
    resolve: {
      vehicleTypes: VehicleTypeResolver,
      vehicleSizes: VehicleSizeResolver,
      equipmentCategories:EquipmentCategoriesResolver,
      bodyTypes:BodyTypeResolver,
      productCatagories:ProductCatagoriesResolver,
      settings:SettingResolver,
      shipper:ShipperResolver,
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'new-order',
    component: FtlOrderComponent,
    resolve: {
      vehicleTypes: VehicleTypeResolver,
      vehicleSizes: VehicleSizeResolver,
      equipmentCategories:EquipmentCategoriesResolver,
      bodyTypes:BodyTypeResolver,
      productCatagories:ProductCatagoriesResolver,
      settings:SettingResolver,
      shipper:ShipperResolver,
    }
  
  }

app layout component code
<app-header></app-header>
<mat-drawer-container [hasBackdrop]="false">
    <mat-drawer [opened]="isSidenavOpened" mode="side">
        <app-side-nav></app-side-nav>
    </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>
        <router-outlet name="layout"></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>

